# why sql query is not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am facing many problems in mysql query.
I am writing a query for order by it is showing me result but not in proper order. my table is

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | NAME   | SALARY |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | hari   | 2000   |
|  2 | haria  | 2000   |
|  3 | ramesh | 2000   |
|  4 | rajesh | 5000   |
|  5 | john   | 21000  |
|  6 | naag   | 45000  |
|  7 | sheena | 22000  |
|  8 | anu    | 34000  |
|  9 | aman   | 15000  |
| 10 | salil  | 9000   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

i want to fetch all salary by order by keyword

```
mysql> select salary from salary order by salary desc;
+--------+
| salary |
+--------+
| 9000   |
| 5000   |
| 45000  |
| 34000  |
| 22000  |
| 21000  |
| 2000   |
| 2000   |
| 2000   |
| 15000  |
+--------+

mysql> select salary from salary order by salary;
+--------+
| salary |
+--------+
| 15000  |
| 2000   |
| 2000   |
| 2000   |
| 21000  |
| 22000  |
| 34000  |
| 45000  |
| 5000   |
| 9000   |
+--------+
```

these results are not showing properly .why order by asc and desc is not working .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Salary field type is? text, int, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable reason is that `SALARY` field is of type `varchar` instead of `int`.
The ordering displayed is if salary is of type `varchar`.
If you made salary an `int` you will have desired ordering.

Comment: thanks..it is working.thank yo very much. you save my time.

Comment: @user7635555 Glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have `text` (or `varchar`) input field type. You can see order is by first character and is valid.

Set `salary` field type to int and will work as you want:

```
ALTER TABLE salary MODIFY salary INT NOT NULL;
```